# dropdown list asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to generate a drop down list for some attributes of my model class. I'm working on an mvc .net application and i'm using razor engine for views. Here is my class :

```
public class present
{       
    public DateTime jour { get; set; }
    public int entree_mat_h { get; set; }
    public int entree_mid_h { get; set; }
    public int sortie_mat_h { get; set; }
    public int sortie_mid_h { get; set; }
    public int entree_mat_m { get; set; }
    public int entree_mid_m { get; set; }
    public int sortie_mat_m { get; set; }
    public int sortie_mid_m { get; set; }
    public string mac { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
```

For example, i want to show a drop down list with values from 0 to 60 for each attribute that is an integer.
Does @html.dropdownlistfor() work in this case?

Comment: If In controller you create a list that have `value` and `text` variables, You can use it. Or yuou can use  `@html.dropdownlist()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your view declare list of possible values, in your case from 0 to 60

```
@{ var values = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, 60)); }
```

Then, you can use it in `DropDownListFor` helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.entree_mat_h, values)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.entree_mid_h, values)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would need to pass a custom select list into it with the values you wanted.

So you would do something like this:

```
   var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

   for(int i=1; i < 61; i++)
   {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = i, Value = i});
   }

   var sl = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
```

Then you would need to pass that to the model

Then in the view you would do the following:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Quantity, @Model.Quantity)
```

Or something along those lines.

Obviously i have used fake names so you would need to make it fit your own model.

Comment: I like Kroliks version much more than mine, much neater.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension method for building your dropdown list from source (select all values projecting to key and value).
example

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToDropDown<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, string> keySelector, Func<TSource, string> elementSelector, Func<TSource,bool> selected)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                return new List<SelectListItem>();
            }
            return source.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = keySelector(c), Text = elementSelector(c), Selected = selected(c) }).ToList();
        }
```

fill your viewBag

```
ViewBag.Languages = languageRepository().GetAll().ToList().ToDropDown(c => c.ID, c => c.Description, c => c.ID == "EN");
```

and finally razor

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddLanguages", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData.Languages, "Please Select")
```